# How to reflect some ASP.NET MVC Controllers outside from MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm a developer from Taipei.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and try to make a Web API project as a web service for N-Tier system. 
My client side is a windows form application and use HttpClient calls Web API project. When I create a new ApiController in a Class Library project and my Web API project reference the Class Library directly, my client side (Windows Form application) works fine. 
In my Class Library project, all my Controller are inherit ApiController. And my Class Library has referenced all Web API dlls right.

Is there any way that my Web API project doesn't reference the Class Library project, but my Web API project use reflection to get all the ApiController type from Class Library dll, and let my Web API work normally?

I can reflect all the ApiController when the Web API Application OnStart. But what should I do next?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It would probably be possible to write an implementation of `IHttpControllerSelector` which looks up your controller types in in your class library `Assembly`. May I ask why you would want to do this rather than just referencing the class library in the normal way?